# How to unregister Spark UDF

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.6

I use Spark 1.6.0 with Java.

I'd like to unregister a Spark UDF. Is there a way like dropping a temporary table `sqlContext.drop(TemporaryTableName)`?

```
    sqlContext.udf().register("isNumeric", value -> {
        if(StringUtils.isNumeric((String)value)) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }, DataTypes.IntegerType);

sqlContext.functionRegistry().listFunction().toSet().toString()
```

I tried to get all functions(including UDF we defined) from current sqlContext, and it works, but is there any way to unregister custom UDF 'isNumeric'

Answer (score 2):

the udf can be unregistered by executing the below SQL.

```
spark.sql("drop temporary function isNumeric")
```

The below snippet shows creating a UDF and dropping of the UDF.

```
scala> spark.udf.register("test", (value: String) => value.toInt)
res16: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,IntegerType,Some(List(StringType)))

scala> spark.catalog.listFunctions.filter(_.name == "test").collect
res17: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.catalog.Function] = Array(Function[name='test', className='null', isTemporary='true'])

scala> spark.sql("drop temporary function test")
res18: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = []

scala> spark.catalog.listFunctions.filter(_.name == "test").collect
res19: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.catalog.Function] = Array()
```

**Spark 1.6v**:

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("drop temporary function test")
{"level": "INFO ", "timestamp": "2017-06-09 05:43:44,650", "classname": "hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver", "body": "Parsing command: drop temporary function test"}
{"level": "INFO ", "timestamp": "2017-06-09 05:43:44,650", "classname": "hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver", "body": "Parse Completed"}
{"level": "INFO ", "timestamp": "2017-06-09 05:43:44,655", "classname": "hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver", "body": "Parsing command: drop temporary function test"}
{"level": "INFO ", "timestamp": "2017-06-09 05:43:44,656", "classname": "hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver", "body": "Parse Completed"}
res7: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [result: string]
```

Comment: I use it in Java code not in shell and I  have tried what you suggest in java                    ` Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.1] failure: ``with'' expected but identifier drop found`

drop temporary function isNumeric

Comment: @JasonG it should work in Java/Scala code context as well. let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: what is the error you are getting and what is your spark version?

Comment: spark version: 1.6.0, `sqlContext.sql("drop temporary function isNumeric");` and the error message is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.1] failure: ``with'' expected but identifier drop found

drop temporary function isNumeric
^

Comment: i tested it in spark 1.6 and it is working fine for me. I am pretty sure there is someother error here in your code.

Comment: Like what I said before I am using it not in spark-shell or scala contex but in java context. I did try and it did failed but thanks a million anyhow and I am still searching for the answer.